unsupported addressable value (argument="target", value=[], code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.13.4) problem with value
I have function in smart contract depositTokens. It has to deposit tokens from user on the contract balance.
    function depositTokens(address[] calldata tokens, uint256[] calldata amounts) external {

        require(tokens.length == amounts.length, "Tokens and amounts length mismatch");

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            require(IERC20(tokens[i]).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amounts[i]), "Transfer failed");
            emit TokensReceived(tokens[i], msg.sender, amounts[i]);
        }

        emit TokensDeposited(msg.sender, trusts[msg.sender].user);

    }

When I call this function on javascript I have an error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: unsupported addressable value (argument="target", value=[ "0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3", "0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512", "0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0", "0xCf7Ed3AccA5a467e9e704C703E8D87F634fB0Fc9", "0xDc64a140Aa3E981100a9becA4E685f962f0cF6C9" ], code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.13.4)
My code on javascript
async phaseFirst() {

       if (window.ethereum) { 
          window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })
            .then(async () => {
              client = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum)
              signer = await client.getSigner()
      
              this.connected = true; 
              this.address = await signer.address;
              console.log(this.address)
              this.balance = await signer.provider.getBalance(this.address)
              console.log(this.balance)
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
            });
        }

        const tokenAddresses = [
            "0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3",
            "0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512",
            "0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0",
            "0xCf7Ed3AccA5a467e9e704C703E8D87F634fB0Fc9",
            "0xDc64a140Aa3E981100a9becA4E685f962f0cF6C9", 
        ];

        const tokenBalances = {};
        const managerContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abiManager, signer)
        var tokenBalancesOnly = [];

        console.log(client)
        for (const tokenAddress of tokenAddresses) {
          
            const tokenContractProvider = new ethers.Contract(tokenAddress, ERC20_ABI, client)
            const tokenContractSigner = new ethers.Contract(tokenAddress, ERC20_ABI, signer)
            const balance = await tokenContractProvider.balanceOf(this.address);
            console.log(balance)
            
            tokenBalances[tokenAddress] = balance;

            tokenBalancesOnly.push(balance);

            const approveTx = await tokenContractSigner.approve(contractAddress, balance);
            await approveTx.wait();
            
        }

        const tx = await managerContract.depositTokens(tokenAddresses, tokenBalancesOnly);
        await tx.wait(); 
        alert('Tokens deposited');

    
      }

I have no idea how to solve this problem. Please help me :( it is my course work.

I'm unable to reproduce the error, though, when I tried using this script. Could you please provide a minimal script like that, which reproduces the error—essentially a minimal reproducible code snippet?
